# Open Remote Terminal Location from Nemo in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: command-line, 13.10, nautilus, ssh, nemo

In Nautilus it was possible to build up a ssh connection to a remote server via passphrase. Then you could bookmark the address and go there really fast. This still works in Nemo with Ubuntu 13.10.

But then, with a right click and using the option "open in a terminal" the user could open a terminal that would show a prompt of the remote server. So you could start to work there right away.

Using Nemo and not Nautilus anymore in Ubuntu 13.10 this doesn't seem to work anymore. I found out that I could use a script:

```
#!/bin/sh
gnome-terminal --execute /usr/bin/ssh user@myserver.net
```

But I would prefer to get back the old behaviour. Is that somehow possible?

Answer (score 2):

You could create two actions in ~/.local/share/nemo/actions.

File remote_terminal1.nemo_action:

```
[Nemo Action]
Name=Open in remote terminal
Comment=Open current folder in remote terminal
Name[de]=Im entfernten Terminal öffnen
Comment[de]=Aktuellen Ordner im entfernten Terminal öffnen
Exec=<remote_terminal.py %F>
Icon-Name=terminal
Selection=none
Extensions=dir;
Dependencies=ssh;
```

File remote_terminal2.nemo_action:

```
[Nemo Action]
Name=Open in remote terminal
Comment=Open this folder in remote terminal
Name[de]=Im entfernten Terminal öffnen
Comment[de]=Diesen Ordner im entfernten Terminal öffnen
Exec=<remote_terminal.py %F>
Icon-Name=terminal
Selection=s
Extensions=dir;
Dependencies=ssh;
```

And finally a Python script remote_terminal.py (must be executable):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import subprocess

path = sys.argv[1]

if '/sftp:' in path:
    sftp = path.split('/sftp:', 1)[1]
    settings = {}
    options, sep, settings['path'] = sftp.partition('/')
    for opt in options.split(','):
        name, sep, value = opt.partition('=')
        settings[name] = value

    cmd = ['gnome-terminal', '-e',
        'ssh %(user)s@%(host)s -t "cd /%(path)s && bash --login"' % settings]
else:
    cmd = ['gnome-terminal', '--working-directory', path]

subprocess.call(cmd)
```

Answer (score 1):

While writing these lines I suffered a further break down with Nemo. Migrating to the 64-bit Version of Ubuntu 14.04 (Mate) I observed that the python scripts stopped working. I found that %F was denying to pass Paramaters any more. So I switched to %U (still working) and adapt the scripts to Bash (I am not a fan of Python, may be a personal taste):

```
#! /bin/bash


# $1 enthält den ersten Parameter

# Testweise Ausgabe aller übergebenen Parameter 
# echo $*
# exit

# der Regex schneidet "sftp://" ab und übergibt den Rest an $sftp
# sftp://root@debbie/var/databases -> root@debbie/var/databases
sftp=`echo $1 | sed 's#^[sftp://]*##'`
# echo $sftp

# Abschneiden des Domain
# root@debbie/var/databases -> root@debbie
domain=`echo $sftp | sed 's#\/.*##'`
# echo $domain

# Abschneiden des Pfades
# root@debbie/var/databases -> var/databases
path=`echo $sftp | sed 's#[^\/]*.##'`
# echo $path
# ssh='ssh '$domain' -t "cd /'$path' && bash --login"'
# echo $ssh

# Der übergebene Pfad startet vom Wurzelverzeichnis / 
gnome-terminal -e 'ssh '$domain' -t "cd /'$path' && bash --login"'

read exit
```

The script does essentially the same as the python script but gives me a better grip on the things I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Using only bash, this is what worked for me in Linux Mint 19 and nemo 3.8.5:

remote_terminal1.action:

```
[Nemo Action]
Name=Open in remote terminal
Comment=Open current folder in remote terminal
Exec=<remote_terminal.sh %U>
Icon-Name=terminal
Selection=none
Extensions=dir;
Dependencies=ssh;
```

remote_terminal2.action:

```
[Nemo Action]
Name=Open in remote terminal
Comment=Open this folder in remote terminal
Exec=<remote_terminal.sh %U>
Icon-Name=terminal
Selection=s
Extensions=dir;
Dependencies=ssh;
```

remote_terminal.sh (don't forget to make it executable with `chmod +x remote_terminal.sh`):

```
#! /bin/bash

# Get host name
domain=`echo $1 | grep -Po "(?<=host=)[^,]*"`

if [ ${#domain} -eq 0 ]; then
    # Not an SSH directory, just open regular terminal
    gnome-terminal --working-directory="$1"
else
    # Get user name
    user=`echo $1 | grep -Po "(?<=user=)[^/]*"`

    # Get path
    path=`echo $1 | grep -Po "(?<=user="${user}").*"`
    if [ ${#path} -eq 0 ]; then
        path=/
    fi

    # Connect
    gnome-terminal -- ssh ${user}@${domain} -t "cd "${path}" && bash --login"
fi
```